# Copy another website's template

Tags: template

i've found a website with a great template. Is there any legal way that I could use the template? I don't want to copy and paste the css file, but is it ok to use the exact colors and styles?

Comment: The only way to legally use another person's design is to get their permission (which may include purchasing the design from them). But unless it's a personal blog, it's not very professional have your site look exactly the same as another site.

Answer (score 3):

Basically no, it's not ok, it's **stealing someone else's work!** Take a look at sites like themeforest.com who have many useful templates for sale.